# Download 4.1GB file stops at 101MB

Tags: browser, download, file-transfer, http

I am trying to download file which is a little bit bigger than 4GB. I tried on Firefox and Chrome and it stops everytime at 101MB. I tried to use an app dedicated for downloading files, but Free Download Manager also failed, but in different way. After every few MBs downloaded there was an error and automatic successful reconnect and another few MBs was downloaded and it was happening in circle. It got to 99% of download, but then it couldn't finish.

I tried on Windows 7 and Windows 2012 Server. File system is NTFS. I downloaded that file from one site, uploaded to second server and now I can't download it from second server.

Comment: What file system are you using? What OS? If you're using FAT32, the file size limit is 4GB and you can't have a file larger than this.

Comment: @Jonno NTFS, Windows 7 and Windows 2012 Server.

Comment: I hate when someone downvotes and runs away withou telling what is wrong. Have a nice day downvoter.

Comment: Well, I restored the balance. Are the downloads always from the same source? Could you link an example?

Comment: @Jonno Thanks. Yes. I downloaded correctly that file from one site, uploaded to second server and now I can't download it from second server. Unfortunately I can't give link since access is restricted.

Comment: Is it specifically this one file on the second server that's failing? Have you tried another >4GB file? (E.G. https://software.opensuse.org/421/en)

Comment: @Jonno The second biggest file from that server is 3.25 Gb and it got through 101 MB. File from your link also.

Comment: The only other relevant question I can think of is whether this problem affects any other machines on your same network? Wondering if it might be a router/ISP issue, but otherwise there's no obvious criteria here to suggest downloads should be failing. My theory was that the files are somehow corrupting on this other server, either when you've uploaded them or redownloaded them, but if the problem occurs even with other mirrors, I'm not sure, sorry.

Comment: @Jonno I tried on two different networks and also on two different machines inside one of those two networks. Result is the same, but the problem occurs only with that one file on that server. "but if the problem occurs even with other mirrors" I wrote that download from your link and download of other 3.25 GB file "got through 101 MB" which means it didn't stop at 101 MB. So other downloads and other mirrors are working.

Comment: You could try installing wget for windows, as long as the target download is the real link to file then wget should succeed. To speed that along you may also want to reduce the amount of back and forth traffic by temporarily disconnecting other devices from your connection/router.

Comment: I understand, subconsciously I read that as it terminated at 101MB. It sounds like it's not a problem with your end then, but a problem with that file on the server. Is the server something you can physically access to check the file is actually intact? It sounds to me like the file is actually only 101MB, and your download manager would error as it will try and receive later chunks of the file asynchronously. As the server can't serve those parts, it would throw an error.

Comment: @moonbutt74 I choose to work around that by reuploading that file in 1GB parts and downloading that separate parts. And I think that this problem is not caused by network or network load, because result was the same in two different networks. Anyway, thanks for tips.

Comment: @Jonno I cannot access that server. I reuploaded that file and result is the same. Entire upload process was successful in both attempts. I don't know how possible is that server uses FAT32 and can't save entire file or there is some other issue.  So to make this work I had to upload that file in parts and download those parts. I guess this is unresolvable with those limited information that I have. When I was downloading with download manager it got to 99% so maybe entire was is uploaded on the server.